# ServiceStack: Logout does not remove session thus requesting authenticated services still works

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I have implemented a custom CredentialsAuthProvider. Logging in works fine. Before I log in, I cannot call any services that require authentication. But after I log in, I do have permission to call those services. Even after I call logout like this:

```
_jsonServiceClient.Get(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "logout"
});
```

I can call those services.

Currently I do not override 'OnLogout' on my custom AuthUserSession class. The requested service does have the `[Authenticate]` attribute. And when adding my AuthFeature plugin, I set `DeleteSessionCookiesOnLogout = true`.

Here is the code I am currently using to test it:

```
var x = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:55776");

//Authenticate
x.Get(new Authenticate
{
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "admin",
    Password = "mypw",
    RememberMe = true
});

//Requesting service that required authentication: Works!
await x.GetAsync(new SyncServiceTimeRequest());

//Logout
x.Get(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "logout"
});

//Requesting service that required authentication: Still works!
await x.GetAsync(new SyncServiceTimeRequest());
```

And here is my AuthFeature

```
var authFeature = new AuthFeature
(
    container.Resolve<IEnigmaUserSession>,
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new EnigmaCredentialsProvider(container.Resolve<EnigmaContext>(), container.Resolve<IEnigmaUserRepository>(), container.Resolve<ILogClient>())
        {
            SessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
        },
        new JwtAuthProvider(this.AppSettings)
        {
            AuthKeyBase64 = this.Settings.ApplicationConfiguration.JwtBaseKey,
            RequireSecureConnection = false,
            ExpireTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromDays(14)
        }
    }
)
{ IncludeAssignRoleServices = false, DeleteSessionCookiesOnLogout = true};
```

Why does my session still exist after logging out? What am I missing?

UPDATE: I am now ussing an HttpJsonClient (from ServiceStack) and inspected the raw headers using Fiddler. This is the result from my logout request:

[image]

UPDATE2:
Headers of the request before the logout looks like this:

[image]

And after the logout it looks like this

[image]

UPDATE3:

```
public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
{
    var authProvider = AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(provider);
    return authProvider.IsAuthorized(this, null);
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the raw HTTP Headers (e.g using Fiddler) and is the behaviour different if you use GetAsync for logout or if you use JsonHttpClient from ServiceStack.HttpClient NuGet package?

Comment: @mythz Using async or not async for every request does not change the behaviour. I have added a screenshot of fiddler to my question. Does this help you?

Comment: logout is expiring the cookies as expected, please post the request after logout

Comment: @mythz You are right, there are less cookies. But how do I restrict coming requests? I have updated my question

Comment: The last request isn’t an Authenticated Request so it shouldn’t be able to call an [Authenticate] Service. Please confirm that /servicetime/sync is a protected Service, if it is what does GetSession().IsAuthenticated in the Service impl return?

Comment: @mythz It is an authenticate-service. I have updated my question and includes 'IsAuthorized'. Note that I am also using a JwtAuthProvider. Could the problem come from there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180443/discussion-between-marco-siffert-and-mythz).

Comment: I asked for the value of GetSession().IsAuthenticated?

Comment: If it’s true, then something is wrong with your configuration, I would need a stand-alone repro on GitHub I can run locally to repro the issue to be able to identify the cause.

Comment: You’re not using JWT to Authenticate as the Request doesn’t contain a BeaterToken.